# Mean Gravitational 'Potential' Energy in Space

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, gravity, astrophysics, universe

Imagine an arbitrary point in space. It is within the gravitational 'potential' of *every* mass (although billions of ly away) in the entire universe.

Since every mass adds a tiny fraction, what is the *total* gravitational 'potential' energy in this point?

**Edit:**

Let point masses be located distance $r_i$ from the point and have masses $m_i$, then the 'potential' is

$$\Phi = - G \sum_{i} \frac{m_i}{r_i}.$$

I'm looking for this value averaged over all points in space. How does this depend on the shape of our universe or can we measure it?

- For example gravity on my location is given by
  $$ 9.81 m/s^2 \text{(earth )} + 6 mm/s^2 \text{(sun)} + 200 pm/s^2 \text{(milky way)} +  ?  \text{(rest of the universe)}.$$

Answer (score 3):

The universe cannot be described at cosmological scales using newtonian physics. We have to use general relativity.

> How does this depend on the shape of our universe or can we measure it?

Ideas like the "shape of the universe" don't make sense in newtonian gravity, so for this reason as well we need general relativity in order to answer your question.

In general relativity, a gravitational potential exists only for static spacetimes. Realistic cosmological models are not static, and therefore we can't define a potential for them.

Comment: Thanks, the best answer so far. Though, the pure formula for $\Phi$ seems not to be limited to Newtonian physics.

Comment: *Though, the pure formula for Φ seems not to be limited to Newtonian physics.* Not sure what you mean by this. $\Phi=- Gm/r$ is newtonian. E.g., it's not the same as the potential that gives the exterior Schwarzschild spacetime. It's a weak-field approximation to that potential. And summing it is also a newtonian approximation -- GR is nonlinear.

Comment: *The universe cannot be described at cosmological scales using newtonian physics* That is not true. Newtonian cosmology (with $\Lambda$) provides a surprisingly good description for large scale cosmological evolution at least from photon decoupling epoch. It also serves  1) as a useful datapoint for Bayesian evaluation of various DM/DE alternative models, 2) as a conceptually simple starting point for various post-Newtonian cosmological frameworks (such as structure formation simulation codes).

Comment: @BenCrowell In GR we also have $m$ (or $E$) and $r$ (with respect to another metric), thus we can calculate $-G m/r$ as well, but it has a different meaning.

Answer (score 1):

> Since every mass adds a tiny fraction, what is the total gravitational
>   potential energy in this point?

There is no unique value of gravitational potential energy, or gravitational potential, at a point in space. It is always measured relative to another point in space.

A mass $m$ in space has gravitational potential energy $U$ with respect to another mass $M$ where the two masses are separated by a distance $r$ of

$$U=\frac{-GMm}{r}$$

Since gravitational potential energy is inversely proportional to $r$ it make sense to choose the zero of gravitational potential energy of $m$ with respect to $M$ for infinitely large $r$.

However, to the extent that there may be a net gravitational force acting on $m$ due to all the masses $M$ acting on $m$, the mass $m$ will experience an acceleration. If we were able to measure the change in velocity of $m$ between two points, we could determine the difference in gravitational potential energy between the two points since the loss in gravitational potential energy between the points will equal the increase in kinetic energy between the points, neglecting any friction in space.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, but formally the formula of $\Phi$ above does not contain any reference point, although the derivation maybe relies on a reference point at infinity.

Comment: @fwgb I drafted my answer before seeing your edit. Even so, with respect to what point in space is phi measured? As far as I am aware, gravitational potential and potential energy is always relative to some point in space. Please convince me otherwise.

Comment: The formula derives form assuming an infinite reference point. But mathematically, one can calculate $\Phi$ even without that assumption.

Comment: *It is always measured relative to another point in space* this is not true in situations where there are no inertial coordinate systems. And this is precisely the case in Newtonian cosmological models. So gravitational potential has a whole new level of ambiguity and to fix it one would need more than specifying “a point”.

Comment: @A.V.S actually my answer was intended in the context of an inertial coordinate system.

Answer (score -1):

It seems to me you are asking about gravitational potential, not gravitational potential energy, since gravitational potential energy is property of some object and not space.

First of all, potential must be specified against some reference point. The Universe as we understand it today is homogeneous and isotropic at large scales. Therefore at large scales all points of space are equivalent and no matter which reference point you will choose (if you average the inhomogeneities at small scales) the difference will be zero. So the distant sources do not matter for the gravitational potential, all that matters is only close surrounding.

You can imagine it this way: the potential tells you how much work you need to do to move some object of unit mass from the reference point to the point in question. But since universe is everywhere (on the large scales) the same and every point on the path is as good as previous one, no work is needed.

Comment: "...So the distant sources do not matter for the gravitational potential..." I don't think so. Surely the potential on large scales is flat, but not zero.

Comment: as i said, potential has no absolute meaning. It has meaning only to specific reference point. In island universe the point is usually taken to be infinity, but in homogeneous universe what point would you choose? and why would another point be different, since the universe is homogeneous?

Comment: See the edit. Its maybe better to say 'potential of the distribution' what I mean.

Comment: @fwgb where did you get the formula for potential from? because as far as i know, that formula is computed for the island universe and cannot be used for our universe.

Comment: @fwgb In a homogeneous model of the universe the potential is the same everywhere, and can be taken to be zero.  Deviations of value and gradient are due to deviations from homogeneity.   I suppose that we know enough about nearby galaxies to do a calculation, but it would still be an approximation.  "We" excludes "me", of course.  :-)

Comment: @garyp All terms in $\Phi$ have the same sign, so nothing cancels out, so $\Phi$ cannot be $0$, thus the mean cannot be $0$.

Comment: @fwgb $\Phi$ itself has no physical significance.  Only $\Delta\Phi$ is physically significant.  Another way of saying the same thing is that $\Phi + A$ is indistinguishable from $\Phi + B$.   So for a constant potential (large-scale homogeneous universe) $0$ J/C is perfectly fine, as is $23.4$ J/C, or any other value.  However, this is true only at large scale.  Locally, there will be variations.

Comment: "-1" Gravitational potential is not a local observable quantity, so just because the universe is homogeneous, does not mean that the potential must have the same value everywhere. A useful analogy (this case is discussed in textbooks on electrodynamics) is vector potential of constant uniform magnetic field: there is homogeneity but the potential varies from point to point.

Comment: My question does not rely on homogeneity, since I'm asking for the mean over all locations.

Comment: @A.V.S. yes, it is not direct observable but its gradient is. So the value of potential cannot change with position vector in homogeneous and isotropic universe. The ambiguity is in the additive constant (which can be time dependent, but not position dependent). In case of EM field, the electromagnetic tensor is invariant under addition of (4-)gradient of scalar field  to 4-potential, which can indeed be position dependent. But this is not the case for gravitational field, which is in analogy to electrostatics, not electrodynamics

Comment: Gradient is also not directly observable here since in this universe **there are no privileged inertial observers**. So gauge transformations in this instance are $\Phi'=\Phi+C+(\mathbf{a} \cdot \mathbf{x})$, or in other words one cannot distinguish if the whole world gained uniform acceleration. Only relative accelerations are observable. And the takeaway from magnetic field analogy should be: transformations of gauge field under space-time symmetries must be equivalent to pure gauge.

Comment: @A.V.S. first of all, in homogeneous and isotropic universe there is privileged inertial observer-the one for whom the symmetry is manifested.Second, why are you mixing inertial observer with uniformly accelerated frames? " one cannot distinguish if the whole world gained uniform acceleration" this claim is not true, unless i misunderstood it.The acceleration is always measurable in classical physics.Yes,in this case one could say there is additional homogeneous gravitational field, but one could not find material source of this field,so it is distinguishable from the field in inertial frame.

Comment: *there is privileged inertial observer-the one for whom the symmetry is manifested* precisely because of the symmetry we see that there are no inertial observers at all: if there was one, then the symmetry would allow us to place another in any point of space, which is impossible since the acceleration relative to the first point is nonzero. *The acceleration is always measurable in classical physics* Why? The first law is only the possibility of inertial observers, not a guarantee of their existence. If there are no inertial observers there are no absolute accelerations.

Comment: @A.V.S. do you have some sources for all your claims? Because it contradicts everything in physics that i have learned. I have never come a cross of a mention that the inertial observer could not be found. On the contrary - f.e. Landau-Lifshitz's Mechanics  explicitly mentions that inertial observer (that is observer to whom the space is homogeneous and isotropic and time homogeneous, that is - the whole acceleration comes from interaction with other bodies) can be always found. Moreover in relativity, the notion of inertial frame is directly build into structure of spacetime itself.

Comment: *Moreover in relativity, the notion of inertial frame is directly build into structure of spacetime itself* you are conflating here two distinct viewpoints. First: gravity is a force (in a 2nd law), then there are no inertial observers and acceleration is a gauge quantity. Second: gravity is geometrized (via Newton–Cartan formalism or its variant), then any point mass not experiencing other forces is inertial and its proper acceleration is zero. Those are complementary viewpoints and I think it should be obvious which viewpoints my statements  refer to.

Comment: … As for sources: Saunders [“Rethinking Newton’s *Principia*”](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/12451/1/Newton%20arXiv.pdf) is a good paper for the philosophy of this issue, but from a practical viewpoint Buchert & Ehlers [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/astro-ph/9510056) is a good summary: specifically start of section 2 plus the note 1.

Comment: … Also IIRC Landau-Lifshitz's approach is the intentional restriction of scope for the sake of brevity, so existence of inertial observers is an imposed assumption rather than a theorem derived from first principles.