# Gravitational potential energy of multi-particle system

Tags: newtonian-gravity, potential-energy

For two particle system, the gravitational potential energy is given by

$$U = - GMm/r.$$

For a three particle system, it is the sum of potential energies of all the possible pairs. This is explained in terms of energy, but i am not able to understand in terms of work done by forces. When i try to bring in a third particle, the forces being vectors add up in vectors and the result is no where equal to he original one.

Explain for 3 or more particle system in terms of work done by forces or refer to any source which i can refer to.

Comment: A similar question was asked yesterday. https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/509916/  You have to distiguish between force, energy and potential.

Comment: The vectors don't have to be added up.  They can be worked with separately

Comment: In a given example, we can only choose one path along which the third mass is brought from infinity and the two forces need not lie along that path leading to components

Comment: If you can calculate the forces you can calculate the potential energy.

Comment: Can you show me how to do it?

Comment: @fwgb it's similar but it is not answering my question.

Answer (score -1):

Not only for 3 particle system but for any system(minimum 2 particles) following definition is valid:-

> The change in potential energy of a system is defined as the negative of work done by the internal conservative forces of the system