# How much gravitational potential is there?

Tags: gravity, potential-energy

Let's say there is some asteroid about to collide with Earth. Due to gravity, the asteroid will be attracted to Earth and will accelerate towards it (as will the Earth, but far less). Thus, it will gain velocity and thus Kinetic Energy. To my understanding, this Kinetic Energy is coming from the Gravitational Potential energy of the Asteroid, which is being converted into Kinetic Energy.

But then, this is the same case for *any* asteroid *anywhere*. Or anything with mass, really. Since the range of gravity is infinite, there will be some attraction between it and earth, and if free from other gravitational forces, they will accelerate towards each other, converting their gravitational potential energy into kinetic energy.

**Question:** Does this mean that any pair of particles with nonzero mass have gravitational potential energy between them? If we could (somehow, impossibly) sum over each pair of particles, would that be the total gravitational potential energy in the universe?

(As for that second part of the question, a simplification could be that we take a 'Universe' of only a couple of particles, or maybe some experiment in a box in outer space with only a couple of particles. If we sum over the gravitational potential energy between each pair of particles, would that be equivalent to the total gravitational potential energy of this system/universe?)

Edit: This is *not* a duplicate of the linked question. The linked question deals with the potential energy at a point, with no reference point at all. In my question, for each point there is a reference point: every other point. To clarify, I want to know about how much energy can be converted into Kinetic Energy by the gravitational force  in the entire universe/for a system of point masses/particles, and whether my notion of gravitational potential energy existing between any two objects/particles with mass is correct or not.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean Gravitational 'Potential' Energy in Space](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/509916/mean-gravitational-potential-energy-in-space)

Answer (score 0):

The mass of an object is not just the mass of the individual particles but as well the energy of the particles.So if we could sum up the potential energy of all the particles then it wouldnt be the total gravitational potential of the universe.
This is without taking into account quantum mechanics.Since the subatomic particles are quantum objects they dont behave like marbles of concentrated mass , they are described by their wavefunction.And since we don't know how gravity works in the microscopic level we can't answer your question.